# IOS/Objective-C: Edit managed object after it is inserted into core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

After inserting a new object in core-data representing a new item and then doing a server call on a background thread to insert it into a database on the back end, I retrieve a new id from the server that I would like to insert back into Core-Data.

Can anyone recommend a save new item and call server without losing the new item in the ManagedObjectContext.  I would like to make the edit to the managed object without having to do an entire NSFetch with an NSPredicate to find it again but right now, it seems to be disappearing.

Here is my code to store the object locally in Core Data and then go go server.  When I get back, however, I don't know how to access this new record.

```
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@“Item” inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        // Initialize Record
        NSManagedObject *record = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        // Populate Record
        [record setValue:name forKey:@“name”];
         // Save Record
        NSError *error = nil;

        if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
          //code to set up background request
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:rq queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *rsp, NSData *data, NSError *err) {
        if (err) {
        } else {
            NSDictionary *jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
             NSInteger insertID = [jsonResults[@"response"][@"insert_id"] integerValue];
            self.newid = *(&(insertID));
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              //          //NEED WAY TO INSERT INTO CORE DATA WITHOUT DOING FULL BLOWN FETCH BUT RECORD SEEMS TO BE GONE
            });
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Please could you clarify ‘record seems to be gone’? Is that pointer now `nil`, or are all the properties of the managed object `nil` or zero, or something else?

Comment: immediately after saving, it still exists i.e. I can log to console record.somproperty.  However, once I go into the synch thread, if I put record.something in the code, it gives a red error message Use of undeclared identifier: record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options, kinda lazy and 'correct'

Assuming that this all originates on the main thread, so `record` is inserted into the main context, you can just capture `record` in the block and update it. Don't make any other changes to it on any other thread. Also, don't delete it or the context before this operation is finished.

Better, get the `objectID` from the new `record`, make sure it's a permanent id and not temporary (see `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:`). Now for whichever thread you're working on you can request, from the appropriate context, performing a block if you need to, the `objectRegisteredForID:`.

Comment: How do I get the objectID from the new record?  is it just record.NSManagedObjectID or something else?

Comment: `objectID` is the method name

Comment: And once I have objecID, something like NSManagedObject *object = objectRegisteredForID.objectid; object.servid = insertID;?

Comment: Am getting Use of undeclared identifier: objectRegisteredForID

Comment: Got it to work once I called method on the managedObjectContext